# How do you start selenium using Chrome driver and all existing browser cookies?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

From what I understand so far, Chrome Driver always starts without any stored browser cookies.

I need the driver start with all the cookies stored by Chrome.

I wonder if there is any way to start the driver with the cookies that are already stored? I'm using C# with .net 4.5.

Comment: I'm not sure your assumption is true. Whenever I start a selenium webdriver session, my login session still exists. Therefore the cookie should be there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes we can do it by invoking saved chrome profile just like firefox profile. below are steps i noted when i am doing bit back ago

in Java, we can do it by using ChromeOptions and Chrome Profile. In chrome navigate to chrome://version/ It will display profile path and Executable path.

As per my working on this, The profile path is  `\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3` This is displaying what is displayed when i navigate to `chrome://version/` in normal chrome browser. In this profile, i navigated to stackoverflow and saved credentials. So used below code

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium_setups\\poi-3.12\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\murali\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

//WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

As per my understanding, i excepted stackoverflow.com page displayed as logged in. but for first time, i am not logged in. so cross checked with chrome://version/ in chrome opened by driver, profile path is displayed as
\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3\Default . then logged manually in that profile it self, which is opened by webdriver and executed gain by closing it.

Finally, page is displayed as logged in. So it may be in java, i hope it will helps you to try in C# .