# Selenium ChromeDriver 'Sync is disabled by your administrator'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run ChromeDriver and try to sign into my google account I get a message saying 'Sync is disabled by your administrator', 'Your administrator has disabled syncing of your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings'.

Then I go to chrome://version/ and in Command Line in the browser it says

```
--disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources
```

When I add arguments such as

```
"--enable-sync" "--enable-web-resources" etc.
```

C# seems to ignore the arguments because next time I start ChromeDriver, in Command Line it still says those arguments are disabled. How can I get ChromeDriver to have full accessibility functions as if I'm running normal Chrome from my taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

I know another method to what you are trying to do. If you want to `"get ChromeDriver to have full accessibility functions as if I'm running normal Chrome from my taskbar?"` you should specify to selenium that you want to use a profile that is not temporary.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\whateveryouwant");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Starting chromedriver like this will cause it to remember cookies, extensions, logins, passwords and so on.

It will be like using selenium on your regular chrome browser.

Comment: So i added the "user-data-dir=file/path/here" and the path I gave it is the path to my Google Chrome I use for all my normal webbrowsing, contains my history, and extensions. When I run my script with Google Chrome already open, my script doesn't do it's automation. If I close Google Chrome and run the script, the script runs fine. Anyway I can have Google Chrome open, and run the script and have it fully execute?

Comment: selenium can't work on already opened browser. On script execution it will start fresh browser and execute on it.  no way to work on already opened browser. to use already profile which has cookies etc.. try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854674/how-do-you-start-selenium-using-chrome-driver-and-all-existing-browser-cookies/36855120#36855120

Comment: in above thread which is from long back, used capabilities, now its depreciated, we need to use ChromeOptions.

Comment: @NathanGorham Yeah I run into that problem too. Unfortunately I had to create a new Chrome profile in order to use this this method. Once you have the new profile, you can save your passwords and extensions as normally.

Comment: I think you should be able to just copy your current profile and run from that though. Sorry for the late reply, busy weekend.

Comment: You could also have your program automatically copy your regular chrome profile to the selenium chrome profile directory before opening chrome driver. Hopefully this solves your problems to a good degree.