# Is there a way to login only once and then skip logging in for next tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chromedriver and Selenium with C#. I would like to only login in my first test and then skip login in next tests to save time. Is there a way to do this?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Temp/chrome");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends up on how you are willing to run test cases. Let say if you are willing to run all test cases on only single logged in browser then yes you can do it.

in beforesuite or beforetest initiate browser and do login. pass same browser instance or webdriver instance to other test cases. It leads to dependency and avoids usage of parallel execution which is very helpful when no of test cases increases.

another way is to use already existing chrome profile. see this for example
[How do you start selenium using Chrome driver and all existing browser cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854674/how-do-you-start-selenium-using-chrome-driver-and-all-existing-browser-cookies/36855120#36855120)

Answer (score 0):

One hack is to get the cookies from the browser on initial login and add these cookies to every new browser (when launched) to skip login
Read this for more info https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html