# How can we use pre-populate cookies in Selenium Web driver to run the tests faster

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How do we `pre-populate` cookies in Selenium Web driver to make the selenium tests run faster ?
If we need to write test for multiple pages how can we have a single reusable method to pre-populate the cookies and how can we use inside tests ?

```
public void addCookie(String name, String value) {

Cookie pagecookieSize = new Cookie.Builder(name, value)
.domain("somedomain.com.au")
.expiresOn(new Date(2020,12,31))                               
.isSecure(true)
.path("/")
.build();
driver.manage().addCookie(pagecookieSize); 
                               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pre-populate cookies means? cookie before starting the selenium or execution. As we know selenium/webdriver starts always new session and cant use old cookies and also we cant save cookies which we see in execution once execution is done.

preferably, use profile concept, create browser profile.. do required navigation's.. so there is cache/cookie/temp what ever may be and call that profile.

here is one of my old post to start chrome with profile
[How do you start selenium using Chrome driver and all existing browser cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854674/how-do-you-start-selenium-using-chrome-driver-and-all-existing-browser-cookies/36855120#36855120)

Comment: Assume if I have 5 tests related to a page. When ever i run these tests i could see Selenium Web Driver takes time to load the page every time. So if I had cookies saved after the first test run, then rest of the 4 tests might run faster I guess. Is there a way to do that in java ? please share an example ? or please let me know if my thinking is completely wrong !

Comment: If you close browser or session in between the tests then their is no possibility to use cookies.